# Where is my resource file

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I've a problem with android and Storage Options (Internal Storage).

I added a SSL certificate in the "raw" directory and i want to write in, into the storage.

In the moment I'm trying it with this code snippet:

```
           InputStream is = SA.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myResource);
           ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

           int nRead;
           byte[] data = new byte[16384];

           while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) 
           {
             buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
           }

           buffer.flush();

           FileOutputStream fos = SA.openFileOutput("Resource.crt", 0);
           fos.write(buffer.toByteArray());
           fos.close();
           is.close();
           buffer.close();
           File f = new File(this.fileList()[0]);
           if(f.exists())
           {
               Log.v("File:", "Found");
           }
           else
           {
               Log.v("File:", "Not found");
           }
```

My File isn't found. I don't know why.

Comment: post fileList() method code? Where the code in question resided Activity or class? More info needed.

Comment: Here this Filelist: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList()

Comment: Try giving your certificate file an entirely lowercase name. If it is indeed called `myResource` it may not be getting compiled into your app as only lowercase letter, numbers, underscores and fullstops are allowed.

Comment: It's all in lowercase. When I do
Log.v("File:", this.fileList()[0]);, then i see my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `fileList` is just returning the filename, but you also need the directory try :

```
File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
if(f.exists()){
    ...
```

Read here :

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage